# Cannot load /home/pavanbsd/wlsplugin/lib/mod_wl.so into server: /home/pavanbsd/wlsplugin/lib/mod_wl.so: undefined symbol: ap_log_rerror

Tags: apache, ubuntu, weblogic, ubuntu-12.04, weblogic12c

Can anyone help me?

```
HTTP -2.4
 wls -12
 wl 11g plugin mod_wl.so
```

While I was installing Apache(HTTP 2.4.9 stable version) on web logic 12c it's generating a syntax error like:

```
  HTTP: Syntax error on line 150 of /home/pavanbsd/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /home/pavanbsd/wlsplugin/lib/mod_wl.so into server: /home/pavanbsd/wlsplugin/lib/mod_wl.so: undefined symbol: ap_log_rerror
```

Thanks,
  -Srikanth

Comment: @TayThomps: When editing, please address *all* issues a question might have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Apache documentation:

"Many third-party modules designed for version 2.2 will otherwise work unchanged with the Apache HTTP Server version 2.4. Some will require changes; see the API update overview."

The version of `mod_wl.so` that came with Weblogic will not work with Apache 2.4 (at least not out of the box). You will probably have to copy in a newer version of the `mod_wl.so` library or go re-download the latest plugin from Oracle. Check what versions of that library you have in `<wl home>/server/plugin/linux/x86_64/` and try using a different one.

Reference:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2544579?tstart=0

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2352914?tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

astling, Thanks for your advice it worked with apache 2.2. Now the issue with accessing weblogic-handler. To test I am using proxy to the Admin server ip, port.

WebLogicHost localhost
     WebLogicPort 8100

SetHandler weblogic-handler

When I tried to access the url from the browser:

```
http://192.168.1.105:3001/mywebapp/console
```

getting 404 --Not Found.

Anything I need to configure for this?

host-level?
permissions?

Comment: Can you ask this as a new question? Since this one has been answered not many people will see this (and in general the way this site works, you should not ask a new question as an answer).